# ColdFusion - CFHTTP (https) sending request over port 80

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfhttp

I am using CFHTTP to connect to a server and post some parameters. I have successfully imported the certificate.

```
<cfhttp url="https://xml.proveid.experian.com/IDSearch.cfc" method="post" result="response" port="443">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(arguments.xml)#"  />   
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(arguments.xml)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

As you can see the request is for port 443 but the error I got back is:

> struct Charset    [empty string]
>   ErrorDetail   Connect Exception: Connect to xml.proveid.experian.com:80
>   [xml.proveid.experian.com/194.60.180.108]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Filecontent   Connection Failure Header   [empty string]
>   Mimetype  Unable to determine MIME type of file.
>   Responseheader     struct [empty]
>   Statuscode    Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
>   Text  YES Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.

Can anyone explain why the request is made on port 80?

Comment: I tried pasting the URL into a browser window and also got a `Connection timed out` error. Maybe it is an issue on their end and not yours?

Comment: He's noting the `:80` where it should be `:443`. He's not asking about the connection timed out.

Comment: My assumption is the response is from 80 since 443 timed out and the server defaults to 80 on that error response? The only thing I can suggest is look at your CF logs and see if the request went out on 443 and not 80. Honestly I have no idea.

Comment: The other thought is the server is configured to not use 443 and requests via TLS redirect to 80. Are you sure you are using the correct URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the specific web service doesn't play well with CFHTTP. So this approach solved the problem.

```
<cfset args.xml = 'xml value'>

<cfinvoke 
                webservice="https://xml.proveid.experian.com/IDSearch.cfc?wsdl"
                method="search"
                returnvariable="aTemp"
                argumentCollection="#args#"> 

</cfinvoke>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://xml.proveid.experian.com/IDSearch.cfc (port 443) is immediately redirecting to http://xml.proveid.experian.com:80/CFIDE/componentutils/cfcexplorer.cfc?method=getcfcinhtml&name=oneninetwo.corpwsdl2.IDSearch&path=/IDSearch.cfc (port 80)

It's that second page that is timing out.

[image]